# Facebook Connect with CodeIgniter login problems

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I'm having a problem using Facebook Connect on my latest website. I'm running it using the CodeIgniter framework and Elliot Haughin's library (http://www.haughin.com/code/facebook/).

Everything is setup okay, when the user goes to login, the request is sent to Facebook okay and returns with the code (which i presume identifies the session?).

However, it doesnt seem to update the library, and after doing all this still thinks that the user is not logged in. It makes me think its a bug in the library itself, but I can't see anyone else with this problem.

I have tried dumping the error log from the library but it doesnt find any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the issues on github it seems you're not the only one:
https://github.com/elliothaughin/codeigniter-facebook/issues/12

One person comments that they used this tutorial instead of Elliot Haughin's library: http://www.dannyherran.com/2011/02/facebook-php-sdk-and-codeigniter-for-basic-user-authentication/